# Qt adding "action" to dynamically added QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

In my ui I have a button, which adds QComboBox (with some items) and QLabel(with some text) when clicked. Variable "index" is the number of added QComboBoxes and QLabels. "ol" is qvector with some data.

```
void MainWindow::on_iAddOtherButton_clicked()
{
   QComboBox *p1 = new QComboBox(this);
   p1->setObjectName("comboBox"+QString::number(index));
   QLabel *p2 = new QLabel(this);
   p2->setObjectName("othLabel"+QString::number(index));
   for(int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(ol.size()); ++i){
      p1->addItem(ol.at(i).getName());
      ui->otherLayout->addWidget(p1,index+1,0);
   }
   p2->setText(...some text...));
   ui->otherLayout->addWidget(p2,index+1,1);
   index++;
}
```

And this works well, in the layout they are in pairs like this:

QComboBox1 QLabel1

QComboBox2 Qlabel2

Now I want to change value of the QComboBox1, after which, text of the QLabel1, will automatically change to something else. 
I tried to do this with connect, but QComboBox on `currentTextChanged()` emits only QString with a new value. Is there some way to emit name of object + new value?
Or there is some completely other solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within your slot, you can call [`sender()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) to get a pointer to the sender of the signal. From there you can decide what to do next based on `sender()->objectName()`.

You might also consider using `setProperty(...)` on the combobox objects to store an index to a vector of pointers to QLabel instances with the vector being a class member. Then you could retrieve the index inside your slot by calling `sender()->property(...)` and use it to access the correct QLabel widget from the vector.

Comment: You could even try to leave out the vector by storing a pointer to the QLabel directly in the dynamic property, but I haven't tried it myself. But basically a `QVariant` should be capable of storing a pointer to a QObject.